# CMake: Cannot set a variable to use OpenCV off

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have the following CMake code segment

```
#OpenCV
option(USE_OPENCV "Use OpenCV data sources" ON)
```

Here I turn the use of OpenCV on by default and then I have:

```
if(USE_OPENCV)
    find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
    if(OpenCV_FOUND)
        include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    else(OpenCV_FOUND)
        set(USE_OPENCV OFF)
        message("OpenCV could not be found. Turning OPENCV OFF.")        
    endif(OpenCV_FOUND)
endif(USE_OPENCV)
```

So I run it on a configuration with no OpenCV and I get the message from CMake: "OpenCV could not be found. Turning OPENCV OFF". However, exiting the screen, I see that the CMake `USE_OPENCV` variable is still turned ON. I was expecting it to be set to OFF.

Is there something I am doing obviously wrong?

[EDIT]
The full CMakeLists file that can produce the behaviour is:

```
project(Test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#OpenCV
option(USE_OPENCV "Use OpenCV data sources" ON)

if(USE_OPENCV)
    find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
    if(OpenCV_FOUND)
        include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    else(OpenCV_FOUND)
        set(USE_OPENCV OFF)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "OpenCV could not be found. Turning OpenCV OFF.")        
    endif(OpenCV_FOUND)
endif(USE_OPENCV)
```

Doing something even simple and pointless like:

```
project(Test2)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#OpenCV
option(USE_OPENCV "Use OpenCV data sources" ON)

if(USE_OPENCV)
    message("Turn it OFF!")
    set(USE_OPENCV OFF)
endif(USE_OPENCV)
```

Even this does not work...

Comment: Have you deleted the CMakeCache.txt or better the complete build directory?

Comment: I do that and no, it did not change anything :/

Comment: Then you have to debug, print messages in every branch and check whether that matches your expectations.

Comment: That is pretty much the gist of my CMakeLists file. I have edited the post to include the full file.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `option` by a simple set?

Comment: Yes, tried set and option both. No change... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so one has to cache the value. So, I did something like:

```
set(USE_OPENCV OFF CACHE BOOL "ON OFF" FORCE)
```

and this seems to work. If someone has a better solution, do update the thread.

Comment: turned off `OPENSSL` in windows using `set(CMAKE_USE_OPENSSL OFF CACHE BOOL "ON OFF" FORCE`

Thanks!